# What is the best online book service for software development references?

Tags: reference

I'm a member of ACM, and I have limited access to both Books 24x7 and Safari Books Online, however if I was interested in moving up to a full account for greater access to other books what online book service would you recommend?

Comment: Why was this closed as not constructive?  I came onto SO today looking for an answer to this very question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari Books Online is my choice, here's a related post:
[Which Online eBook Reference Library Do You Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179447/which-online-ebook-reference-library-do-you-use)

Answer (score 4):

[Safari Books Online](http://www.safaribooksonline.com/whysafari/try-safari.php) has a corporate subscription service which companies appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

I have Books 24x7, it has a great range of books and the search functionality works well. It also gives you recommendations from other users, and if other people from your organization join then it tells you about books they have recommended.

Comment: If you're a FireFox user and have the Stylish plugin, I set up a style sheet for books24x7 that uses a 14-point georgia font for the text instead of the 10-point arial that is the default. It makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

[Audible](http://www.audible.com) - Self Development, Business and Education sections!

Answer (score 1):

Safari Books Online..  By far..
http://techbus.safaribooksonline.com:80/

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how much you want O'Reilly and Pearson Technology books (which includes many smaller publishers like Peachpit).  Safari has exclusive rights to those titles. Safari also has a monthly subscription level so you don't have to commit to an entire year.