# Which online eBook reference library do you use?

Tags: reference-library

I use Safari Books Online as a reference library and to evaluate book before I decide to buy a paper copy, but it doesn't include any Apress books. Is there a better alternative you would recommend?

Edit: Safari Books Online now includes Apress titles which makes it the most complete reference library on the web in my opinion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With my [ACM membership](http://pd.acm.org/), I get access to both Safari and Books24x7 (this includes Apress).

The selection is reduced from the total offering of those sites (600 in Safari only available to professional members and 500 in Books24x7 available to both student and professional members), but I find it's well worth the ACM annual membership, especially when you factor in the other benefits.

There is a discount for first year members: http://learnmore.acm.org/joinacm5.html

Our local library ([nutrias.org](http://nutrias.org)) does have ebooks for free also, but I haven't looked to see if they have technical books.  In addition, they are term-limited with DRM (yuk).

Comment: The ACM gets Safari too? I knew about Books24x7. I must check this out when I get home.

Comment: Yep - it's two separate links from the members page.

Comment: ...And I was already thinking about getting a professional ACM membership, but wow I didn't realize it got that much, hm.

Comment: If you are new to ACM you can join at a 15 percent discount.
http://learnmore.acm.org/joinacm5.html

Comment: ...Figures, I just signed up after seeing this, THEN you post that ;)

Comment: Wow, I've been a member for years and I didn't know about this. I'd mark this up twice if I could, thanks!!

Comment: pd.acm.org is one of the primary reasons I maintain my ACM membership.  In *almost* every instance where a title has been recommended, either through research online or training courses, I've found that they were readily available through either of the two book services provided by ACM.  Also, don't forget about the Element K training classes and virtual labs, which is also available with ACM membership.

Answer (score 4):

I use paper books and use [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com) as a reference

Answer (score 2):

Cade,

Not the answer you are looking for but if you are paying for Safari check around your local library systems and make sure you cannot get it for free.

Comment: I assume you can only use it for free when you are in the library though, not from home...

Comment: Depends. I just looked into it for my county and it's available remotely, just requiring you to enter your library card #. Nice tip, Flory! +1

Answer (score 1):

Here in Santa Clara county, California, we can access the library e-resources, including Safari, from the library's website.